# Does google nl api support "word hints"

Tags: google-cloud-nl

This article references a feature called "Word Hints."  But I am not able to find more info on how to use that.  Anyone run into this?
https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/07/the-latest-for-Cloud-customers-machine-learning-and-west-coast-expansion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word hints are available for the Speech API (docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig#SpeechContext)) but this feature is not currently supported for the NL API.